# Do angels still visit us on earth

Tags: biblical-basis, angels, early-church, church-fathers

I know that throughout the Bible Angels met with humans for very specific reasons. An obvious example can be found in **Luke 1:26-38**. Gabriel speaks to Mary and informs her she will give birth to a son who is to be named Jesus. Do Angels still visit us on earth and interact with humans today?

Comment: As most of the passages I think you would cite seem to make clear, the angels didn't "exist on earth", they were sent from Heaven and only stayed to give a message. So are you asking if any angels still come to visit us today? "exist on earth" is just sort of ambiguous...

Comment: Are you looking for Biblical quote or anecdotal evidence? The latter will possibly cause the question to be closed.

Comment: ^^^... Of course, if asking for *empirical* evidence the answer becomes fairly easy...

Comment: @Doubting I appreciate the help. I have updated both the title and question to reflect the questions true intent.

Comment: With the edit clarifying the intent... Well, that won't have scriptural basis (since it is strictly today). Empirical evidence to date is zero. That leves subjective and anecdotal only - not sure that leaves room for a good answer... I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I am not sure that "strictly today" makes something lack scriptural basis. Is there any scripture that would imply angels would continue to visit all throughout human existence or possibly any prophesy that would suggest this. Are there any Early Church Fathers writings discussing angelic experiences and/or Angels visiting us on earth in any way?

Comment: This looks like a truth question. Could you ask for answers from a particular Christian perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They certainly exist, they exist in the past, present and future.  The Bible speaks of them in all three tenses to the last age of man.

Do they interact with humans today? I can see no reason they would not, but it is not an absolute thing, where the Bible says this is the way it is exactly, as far as when and how they interact with men.

My best guess is that they interact all the time, they seem to deliver messages a lot, I suspect they still do. I have read and heard stories and perhaps had a few interact with me and I never knew it.  They can appear like men and save your life. Carry you over a mountain pass through snow and then disappear.

Comment: I suspect this answer would benefit from some citations

Comment: @Hammer I appreciate the help. I have updated both the title and question to reflect the questions true intent.

Answer (score 4):

Hebrews 13:2 reminds us to show love and hospitality towards all, "for in doing so, some have entertained angels," unaware. When Samsons parents were told they were going to have a child, they too were unaware that they were in the presence of an angel, until after they sacrificed, the angel went away dramatically revealing what he was.

There is nothing to suggest that angels no longer visit Earth*, but nothing says that says we will recognize them as such when they do.

*ok, possibly one could say that because we have the Bible, God no longer requires messengers (and by definition an *angelos*' job is a messenger) but that would just be speculation.

Comment: Sorry! Dang autocorrect.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous stories, particularly in the lives of the Saints. But traditionally every Christian is regarded as having their own guardian angel. So to answer your question in perhaps a less spectacular and significant fashion, Yes, and constantly.

Comment: According to which traditions does every Christian have their own guardian angel?

Answer (score 0):

No angels do not still intervene in the world today. If every Christian in the world had a Guardian Angel, bad things would not happen to any Christian because they would be protected. The Bible also says that the sole purpose of the creation of angels was for them to worship God, not protect his people.

As for the "stories" of angels that help you in the form of a human, what's to say that isn't a person full of the Holy Spirit? What happens when the person is then suddenly gone? In Acts, the spirit teleported Philip to speak to the Ethiopian Eunuch, then he teleported him back to his home immediately.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We need some sources in your answer. Just saying the "Bible says" is not enough, although, quoting the Bible is always acceptable. Look up these verses you mention, quote them, the fill out your answer, by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Angels would exist even today, as well have the same authority God has intended for them. No your likely not going to notice them and if u think u do u may consider it the possibility u just saw a demon. Demons would hope to allude you from the truth and in doing so will attempt to taint the faith in regard to what u believe rather than attempt to discredit it altogether. Just because you have a Guardian Angel doesn't make you exempt from bad things. If it did we wouldn't need prayer. This is how God answers our prayers many times by sending our angels to intervene when truly necessary. And remember that just because a Guardian Angel is appointed to you that I you have no faith then you also receive very little of any assistance. However, should someone else pray for you it exists the great possibility that the unfaithful may be influenced by their Guardian Angel. Interesting topic and wondrous to think about. When you pray to God please don't discount these facts and watch miracles happen in your life as they continue to happen in mine. Simply put, a prayer answered in any form is a miracle of intervention by our Heavenly Father who really does care when we need him. Not so much to the frivolous requests. Think about your prayer before you make the request so it is meaningful and not in vain.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE, and when you get the chance, I'd encourage you to read [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).  As it stands, this is good pastoral advice, but not really a good academic answer.  You may want to spend some time tightening up your grammar and sourcing your claims.